# Snowflake Account expiry

Tags: authentication, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am using a python connector to use snowflake from backend , I need a query or something to check whether my account is valid or it got expired basically for trial account, In Snowflake UI it is showing the error but when using the python connector I need to get a similar error like at the time of login itself

Comment: Wouldn't the login itself timeout in that case when connecting from python?Or are you still seeing the connection get through successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"you trail has expired" is not really a thing that people "normally" need to programmatically know about.

Unless you are repeatedly "programmatically" making more accounts, which seems against the purpose of the free accounts.

I would think that you python would start failing to log in, which it should back off and try again after an escalating timer (1s, 10s, 60s,..) but at the same time tell you there is a failure (of some sort) and at the time the account expires. You stop running your automation/python code.